# Consulta em nome de tabela por Reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta na tabela, que o nome dela vai vir pelo escopo do método, mas não permite eu usar `Select();` ou `Where();`

```
System.Type referenceTableType = 
System.Type.GetType("MeuProjeto.Model." + typeRequest.ReferenceTable);
object TabelaPraConsulta = Activator.CreateInstance(referenceTableType); 
var x= Database.Set(TabelaPraConsulta).Select(qw => qw.id = id); // isso nao é possivel
```

Não sei muito bem como fazer isto, nunca usei *reflection*.

Então gostaria de conseguir fazer uma consulta com o nome da tabela que vem no typeRequest.ReferenceTable 
mas eu nao sei como

Comment: Que bom, e provavelmente não é necessário. Quase todo uso de *reflection* está errado. Sem contexto não posso ajudar mais, mas neste caso do jeito está, simplesmente não faça e tudo resolvido.

Comment: como eu poderia detalhar mais meu problema?

Comment: Fazendo como o Ciro :)

Comment: Isso tem cara de [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy).

Comment: Não consegui entender muito bem o que e por que você quer fazer isso, ainda mais dessa forma... Não seria o caso de usar `Generics` ao invés de `Reflection`? Ou até mesmo um simples `typeof()`

Comment: é, no caso eu queria setar o nome da tabela com o nome dela. nao deixar pre definido.

Comment: tentei  colocar Database."nome da tabela".where(etc, etc); mas nao funciona

Comment: Como uma string no caso

Comment: @mateusandrade o que você quis dizer com *setar o nome da tabela com o nome dela. nao deixar pre definido*?

Comment: @Alisson isto mesmo, desculpa se expliquei mal

Comment: Passe o contexto de porque você quer fazer isso pois acho que pela própria orientação a objeto você consegue contornar esse tipo de coisa, usar classe genéricas talvez seria uma boa.